# UISlider add label show constant

Tags: ios, label, uislider

Hi I have data coming from the server, my slider is set to server settings but I need display a label with the same values of the slider in the Thumb This is working the problem is that.  the label is not visible. is visible only when you touches the slide I need to be visible without touching the slider

this is my code

```
float registerOne = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"POP01"];     //Data from server save whit NSUserDefaults 
    SinP.value = registerOne;
    UIImageView *handleView1 = [SinP.subviews lastObject];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label = (UILabel*)[handleView1 viewWithTag:1010];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:handleView1.bounds];
    label.tag = 1010;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.hidden=NO;
    handleView1.hidden=NO;
    handleView1.alpha=1;
    handleView1.backgroundColor= [UIColor blueColor];
    [handleView1 addSubview:label];
    [SinP addSubview:handleView1];
    label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]    valueForKey:@"POP01"];
     NSLog(@"WHERE IS MY LABEL %@",label.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

simple animation

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 0.2;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        float registerOne = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     floatForKey:@"POP01"];
        SinP.value = registerOne;
        UIImageView *handleView1 = [SinP.subviews lastObject];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label = (UILabel*)[handleView1 viewWithTag:1001];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:handleView1.bounds];
        label.tag = 1001;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        handleView1.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [handleView1 addSubview:label];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",       self.SinP.value];

      });
```